# XLRD doesn't seem to be finding my variable inside the file

Tags: python

I'm brand new to python and I'm trying to read an .xls file and look at the first column of each row to see if it matches my variable. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly and hoping someone can help me out. My end goal is to find each row that starts with this variable in it's first column and then delete the rest of the rows or write those rows to another file. Here is what I've been working with:

```
import xlrd

file_location = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Test.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

mid=5348120284087186

for row in range (sheet.nrows):
    var1=''+sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    if var1==mid:
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            print sheet.cell_value(row, col)
```

This is what I've been using to attempt a test to see if it can initially find the rows that match the ID. `var1` syntax was suggested by a friend to cheat the cell_value into a string. I can view the xls file and know the variable is there on multiple rows, but this doesn't result in anything. I have also tried a simpler variation where it just checks the variables and then prints the first cell_value but still results with no output. Thanks in advance for any insight

EDIT:

As suggested, I adjusted my recursion to what I understood needed to be changed to this:

```
for row in range (sheet.nrows):
    var1=str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    if var1==str(mid):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            print sheet.cell_value(row, col)
```

However, this is still resulting in no output in IDLE when testing

Comment: In your updated code, did you also make sure `mid` was a string?

Comment: Yes, I have mid="5348120284087186" now. I feel like the cell within the sheet might have spaces generated? XLRD gives it a data type of 1 which is a Unicode String. How might I have it just check to see if the `mid` variable is within the `var1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> `var1` syntax was suggested by a friend to cheat the cell_value into a string.

Which implies that `var1` is a string type.

However, you are comparing it with `mid`, which is not a string type.  Therefore `var1 == mid` will always evaluate to false.  Ensure your variables are of the same type before comparing.

Additionally, the syntax you use for `var1` is *gross*.  If you really want a string out of it, just use `var1 = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))`.

Troubleshooting these sorts of problems can be greatly aided with the following:

```
for row in range (sheet.nrows):
    var1=str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))

    print mid, var1, mid==var1, type(mid), type(var1)

    if var1==str(mid):
```

If you are concerned about superflous spaces, do

```
var1 = str(sheet.cell_value(row,0)).strip()
```

Comment: Great, thanks for all your help. The strip() did the trick, must have been the spaces. I'll keep the testing methods in mind in the future.